# ReflectionClass::getProperties() : properties in order of declaration?

Tags: php, reflection

When running this code:

```
class MyClass {
    public int $one;
    public int $two;
    public int $three;
}

$rc = new ReflectionClass(MyClass::class);
foreach ($rc->getProperties() as $property) {
    echo $property->getName() . "\n";
}
```

, the properties in the output are ordered like in the class declaration:

```
one
two
three
```

Can I rely on this ordering, concerning `ReflectionClass::getProperties()`?

Context: I want to use a class to represent a specific file format, each class property being a field in the file (using Php attributes to characterize each of them). The ordering of the fields in the file is of course a necessity.

Comment: I can't give you an official answer, but some of the [PHP tests](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/reflection/tests/ReflectionClass_getProperties_003.phpt) show that they expect that to be true. However, having built exactly what you are talking about in the past, I'd push you to PHP Attributes which are more explicit and will give future readers more context for what is going on.

Comment: For reference for the attribute version, here's a [sample based](https://3v4l.org/THsbf#v8.1.9) on my existing code. My DTO uses CPP which I really like but also looks pretty messy with attributes.